# Does MPMusicPlayerController update Play Count?

Tags: ios, core-audio, mpmusicplayercontroller

In my testing, it seems that playing MPMediaItem through MPMusicPlayerController does not update the Play Count (using iPod or application instance)

Can anyone confirm this? I haven't seen anything in the documentation either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests, the play count gets updated for both `iPodMusicPlayer` and `applicationMusicPlayer`.

First I skipped through to the end of the song. Then I jumped back to the previous track and tested the play count using `valueForProperty` after getting a `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`:

```
- (void)handleNowPlayingItemChange:(NSNotification *)itemNotification {
     MPMediaItem *currentMediaItem = [[self musicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
     NSNumber *currentPlayCount = [currentMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];
     NSLog(@"Current play count: %@", currentPlayCount);
}
```

Comment: Great. I see now that you have to click "Sync" in iTunes to get this data to come across.